# Is there a way to set an element's onload via CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a .js file that allows me to detect what browser or OS is being run and then integrate it into the CSS, making sort of "if" statements, like, if mobile, set this to have these attributes. So I want a specific javascript function to fire when the window or body is loaded if and only if the platform is mobile, else run a default function. I have the capability to do this, I believe, but I can't seem to locate a way to set the onload parameter on body{} via CSS, in order to set up the if statement regarding the body and the platform being mobile. Is there a way in CSS to change onload?

Here's the browser selector: http://www.dreamquest.io/css_browser_selector.js

And here's an example of what I'd want the CSS to look like.

```
.mobile body {
  onload = "javascript:setBackgroundMobile";
}
```

Edit: Okay, so, I've added this code to my javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  if (window.screen.availHeight < "600") {
    setBackgroundMobile();
  }
  else if (window.screen.availHeight >= "600") {
    setBackground();
  }
});
```

On my android phone, and on my Windows PC both, the else is ran successfully. Which I think is because on my phone, my screen rotation is vertical at first. Just verified, yes, when the site is loaded in on the vertical it loads the second if, and if it's on horizontal, it does the first. Which is problematic, but it's whatevs. I'll figure something out. Thanks for information, guys.

Comment: Use `media-queries`

Comment: *set the onload parameter on body{} via CSS*  --- ????? it's unclear to me what you want if you already have the js file to do the detection why you nedd css onload?

Comment: Provide your code.

Comment: Because this .js file is a CSS-specific browser selector. Here is my website: http://www.dreamquest.io

Comment: Uh... you can't use CSS to change JavaScript.

Comment: I wouldn't changing javascript, I'd be changing HTML to specify which javascript function to run.

Comment: I have a long set of code, Ali. Here's the .js file, and here's an example of what I'd want to do. One minute, apparently hitting enter here just saves the edit. I'm going to provide the code in an edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, there is no way to do that with CSS.**

CSS manages styles. It is aware of HTML attributes, because you can use them in selectors, but that's it. CSS cannot create or modify them, and probably never will, since it was not designed for that purpose.

Comment: Looking at the browser selector I provided in above, is there a way to set up an if statement involving a window.onload detecting which platform the user is on? I don't know javascript or jquery very well at all and that .js file,although short, is very hard for me to understand.

Comment: @resriel, the crux of the matter is that you're trying to use an `onload` attribute to run code on page initialization. We actually stopped doing that a few years ago, because, as you realized, it is *very* primitive. You should bind a function to the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event (either in plain JS or through a toolkit) and check for a mobile user agent there instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have this by using http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp

and then loading a new css flie. you should try and use CSS for anyone with javascript disabled.